# how to sort a json file in shell script based on a given key?

Tags: json, shell, sorting, unix, sh

I wanted to sort the file which have json data on basis of a key(**fare**) in a shell script (.sh) file.Is there a way to acheive the same ?

```
{ "route":[
   {"match":"true","column":"10","fare":"120.0","source":"false","length":"1","name":"41","row":"4","width":"1","zIndex":"0"},
   {"match":"true","column":"9","fare":"110.0","source":"false","length":"1","name":"37","row":"3","width":"1","zIndex":"0"},
   {"match":"true","column":"8","fare":"500.0","source":"false","length":"1","name":"33","row":"2","width":"1","zIndex":"0"},
   {"match":"true","column":"7","fare":"510.0","source":"false","length":"1","name":"29","row":"1","width":"1","zIndex":"0"},
   {"match":"true","column":"6","fare":"50.0","source":"false","length":"1","name":"29","row":"0","width":"1","zIndex":"0"}
   ]
};
```

Comment: Suggest using a json tool, like [json](http://trentm.com/json/) or [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Answer (score 2):

```
jq '.route = (.route | sort_by(.fare))' file.json
```

```
{
  "route": [
    {
      "zIndex": "0",
      "match": "true",
      "column": "9",
      "fare": "110.0",
      "source": "false",
      "length": "1",
      "name": "37",
      "row": "3",
      "width": "1"
    },
    {
      "zIndex": "0",
      "match": "true",
      "column": "10",
      "fare": "120.0",
      "source": "false",
      "length": "1",
      "name": "41",
      "row": "4",
      "width": "1"
    },
    {
      "zIndex": "0",
      "match": "true",
      "column": "6",
      "fare": "50.0",
      "source": "false",
      "length": "1",
      "name": "29",
      "row": "0",
      "width": "1"
    },
    {
      "zIndex": "0",
      "match": "true",
      "column": "8",
      "fare": "500.0",
      "source": "false",
      "length": "1",
      "name": "33",
      "row": "2",
      "width": "1"
    },
    {
      "zIndex": "0",
      "match": "true",
      "column": "7",
      "fare": "510.0",
      "source": "false",
      "length": "1",
      "name": "29",
      "row": "1",
      "width": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that the sorting is **lexical** ("50" is in the middle). This is because the values are *strings* not *numbers*. To get numeric sorting, we need to cast as a number

```
jq '.route = (.route | sort_by(.fare | tonumber))' file.json
```

```
{
  "route": [
    {
      "zIndex": "0",
      "match": "true",
      "column": "6",
      "fare": "50.0",
      "source": "false",
      "length": "1",
      "name": "29",
      "row": "0",
      "width": "1"
    },
    {
      "zIndex": "0",
      "match": "true",
      "column": "9",
      "fare": "110.0",
      "source": "false",
      "length": "1",
      "name": "37",
      "row": "3",
      "width": "1"
    },
    {
      "zIndex": "0",
      "match": "true",
      "column": "10",
      "fare": "120.0",
      "source": "false",
      "length": "1",
      "name": "41",
      "row": "4",
      "width": "1"
    },
    {
      "zIndex": "0",
      "match": "true",
      "column": "8",
      "fare": "500.0",
      "source": "false",
      "length": "1",
      "name": "33",
      "row": "2",
      "width": "1"
    },
    {
      "zIndex": "0",
      "match": "true",
      "column": "7",
      "fare": "510.0",
      "source": "false",
      "length": "1",
      "name": "29",
      "row": "1",
      "width": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I needed to remove the trailing comma to get valid JSON

Comment: Can u suggest me to sort json without using any third party tool i.e. pure shell scripting?

Comment: No. JSON, like XML, is sufficiently complex that it is beyond the capability of regular expressions to parse. Although, one could write a small javascript program and run it with something like node.js.